Minecraft forge 1.20.1 prevent hopper taking item from input slot
I made a block entity in forge 1.20.1, I want to prevent hopper from taking input slot item, i tried to override the extractItem method, it prevented hopper from taking input slot item, but the player also unable to take/change the item in input slot unless the slot is empty.
Anyone know how to solve it? Thanks!
FluidSeparatorBlockentity Class
package coolerpromc.chemmaster.block.entity;

import coolerpromc.chemmaster.handler.CustomItemHandler;
import coolerpromc.chemmaster.recipe.FluidSeparatingRecipe;
import coolerpromc.chemmaster.screen.FluidSeparatorMenu;
import net.minecraft.core.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.core.Direction;
import net.minecraft.nbt.CompoundTag;
import net.minecraft.network.chat.Component;
import net.minecraft.world.Containers;
import net.minecraft.world.MenuProvider;
import net.minecraft.world.SimpleContainer;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.player.Inventory;
import net.minecraft.world.entity.player.Player;
import net.minecraft.world.inventory.AbstractContainerMenu;
import net.minecraft.world.inventory.ContainerData;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.entity.BlockEntity;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockState;
import net.minecraft.world.phys.AABB;
import net.minecraftforge.common.capabilities.Capability;
import net.minecraftforge.common.capabilities.ForgeCapabilities;
import net.minecraftforge.common.util.LazyOptional;
import net.minecraftforge.items.IItemHandler;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import net.minecraft.world.level.Level;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class FluidSeparatorBlockEntity extends BlockEntity implements MenuProvider {
    private static final int INPUT_SLOT = 0;

    private final CustomItemHandler itemHandler = new CustomItemHandler(3){
        @Override
        protected void onContentsChanged(int slot) {
            setChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isItemValid(int slot, @NotNull ItemStack stack) {
            return slot == INPUT_SLOT;
        }

        @Override
        public @NotNull ItemStack extractItem(int slot, int amount, boolean simulate) {
            if (slot == INPUT_SLOT) {
                return ItemStack.EMPTY;
            }
            return super.extractItem(slot, amount, simulate);
        }
    };

    private LazyOptional<IItemHandler> lazyItemHandler = LazyOptional.empty();

    protected final ContainerData data;
    private int progress = 0;
    private int maxProgress = 78;


    public FluidSeparatorBlockEntity(BlockPos pPos, BlockState pBlockState) {
        super(ModBlockEntities.FLUID_SEPARATOR_BE.get(), pPos, pBlockState);
        this.data = new ContainerData() {
            @Override
            public int get(int pIndex) {
                return switch (pIndex) {
                    case 0 -> FluidSeparatorBlockEntity.this.progress;
                    case 1, 2 -> FluidSeparatorBlockEntity.this.maxProgress;
                    default -> 0;
                };
            }

            @Override
            public void set(int pIndex, int pValue) {
                switch (pIndex) {
                    case 0 -> FluidSeparatorBlockEntity.this.progress = pValue;
                    case 1, 2 -> FluidSeparatorBlockEntity.this.maxProgress = pValue;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull <T> LazyOptional<T> getCapability(@NotNull Capability<T> cap, @Nullable Direction side) {
        if(cap == ForgeCapabilities.ITEM_HANDLER) {
            return lazyItemHandler.cast();
        }

        return super.getCapability(cap, side);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoad() {
        super.onLoad();
        lazyItemHandler = LazyOptional.of(() -> itemHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateCaps() {
        super.invalidateCaps();
        lazyItemHandler.invalidate();
    }

    public void drops() {
        SimpleContainer inventory = new SimpleContainer(itemHandler.getSlots());
        for(int i = 0; i < itemHandler.getSlots(); i++) {
            inventory.setItem(i, itemHandler.getStackInSlot(i));
        }
        Containers.dropContents(this.level, this.worldPosition, inventory);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getDisplayName() {
        return Component.translatable("block.chemmaster.fluid_separator");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public AbstractContainerMenu createMenu(int pContainerId, Inventory pPlayerInventory, Player pPlayer) {
        return new FluidSeparatorMenu(pContainerId, pPlayerInventory, this, this.data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void saveAdditional(CompoundTag pTag) {
        pTag.put("inventory", itemHandler.serializeNBT());
        pTag.putInt("fluid_separator.progress", progress);

        super.saveAdditional(pTag);
    }

    @Override
    public void load(CompoundTag pTag) {
        super.load(pTag);
        itemHandler.deserializeNBT(pTag.getCompound("inventory"));
        progress = pTag.getInt("fluid_separator.progress");
    }

    public void tick(Level pLevel, BlockPos pPos, BlockState pState) {
        ItemStack inputStack = this.itemHandler.getStackInSlot(INPUT_SLOT);
        if (inputStack.getCount() < 2) {
            resetProgress();
            return;
        }
        if(hasRecipe()) {
            increaseCraftingProgress();
            setChanged(pLevel, pPos, pState);

            if(hasProgressFinished()) {
                craftItem();
                resetProgress();
            }
        } else {
            resetProgress();
        }
    }

    private void resetProgress() {
        progress = 0;
    }

    private void craftItem() {
        Optional<FluidSeparatingRecipe> recipe = getCurrentRecipe();
        if (recipe.isPresent()) {
            List<ItemStack> results = recipe.get().getOutputs();
            ItemStack inputStack = this.itemHandler.getStackInSlot(INPUT_SLOT);
            if (inputStack.getCount() < 2) {
                // If there are not enough items, do not proceed with crafting
                return;
            }

            // Extract the input item from the input slot
            this.itemHandler.internalExtractItem(INPUT_SLOT, 2, false);

            // Loop through each result item and find suitable output slots
            for (ItemStack result : results) {
                int outputSlot = findSuitableOutputSlot(result);
                if (outputSlot != -1) {
                    this.itemHandler.setStackInSlot(outputSlot, new ItemStack(result.getItem(),
                            this.itemHandler.getStackInSlot(outputSlot).getCount() + result.getCount()));
                } else {
                    // Handle the case where no suitable output slot is found
                    // This can be logging an error, throwing an exception, or any other handling logic
                    System.err.println("No suitable output slot found for item: " + result);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int findSuitableOutputSlot(ItemStack result) {
        // Implement logic to find a suitable output slot for the given result
        // Return the slot index or -1 if no suitable slot is found
        for (int i = 0; i < this.itemHandler.getSlots(); i++) {
            // Ensure we do not place the output item in the input slot
            if (i == INPUT_SLOT) {
                continue;
            }

            ItemStack stackInSlot = this.itemHandler.getStackInSlot(i);
            if (stackInSlot.isEmpty() || (stackInSlot.getItem() == result.getItem() && stackInSlot.getCount() + result.getCount() <= stackInSlot.getMaxStackSize())) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private boolean hasRecipe() {
        Optional<FluidSeparatingRecipe> recipe = getCurrentRecipe();

        if (recipe.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        List<ItemStack> results = recipe.get().getOutputs();

        for (ItemStack result : results) {
            if (!canInsertAmountIntoOutputSlot(result) || !canInsertItemIntoOutputSlot(result.getItem())) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    private Optional<FluidSeparatingRecipe> getCurrentRecipe(){
        SimpleContainer inventory = new SimpleContainer(this.itemHandler.getSlots());
        for (int i = 0; i < itemHandler.getSlots(); i++) {
            inventory.setItem(i, this.itemHandler.getStackInSlot(i));
        }

        return this.level.getRecipeManager().getRecipeFor(FluidSeparatingRecipe.Type.INSTANCE, inventory, level);
    }

    private boolean canInsertAmountIntoOutputSlot(ItemStack result) {
        for (int i = 1; i < this.itemHandler.getSlots(); i++) {
            ItemStack stackInSlot = this.itemHandler.getStackInSlot(i);
            if (stackInSlot.isEmpty() || (stackInSlot.getItem() == result.getItem() && stackInSlot.getCount() + result.getCount() <= stackInSlot.getMaxStackSize())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean canInsertItemIntoOutputSlot(Item item) {
        for (int i = 1; i < this.itemHandler.getSlots(); i++) {
            ItemStack stackInSlot = this.itemHandler.getStackInSlot(i);
            if (stackInSlot.isEmpty() || stackInSlot.getItem() == item) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    private boolean hasProgressFinished() {
        return progress >= maxProgress;
    }

    private void increaseCraftingProgress() {
        progress++;
    }
}


CustomItemHandler Class
package coolerpromc.chemmaster.handler;

import net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.items.ItemStackHandler;

public class CustomItemHandler extends ItemStackHandler {
    public CustomItemHandler(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    public ItemStack internalExtractItem(int slot, int amount, boolean simulate) {
        return super.extractItem(slot, amount, simulate);
    }
}



I expecting the hopper is not able to take item from input slot, and player is able to change item or take item as usual like any normal slot.

You should edit the Hopper.class and patch its method to extract items.
